# C++ Builder - Multiple changes to main menu

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, c++builder, vcl

I need to make multiple enable/disable changes to a main menu in a C++ Builder VCL application.

When the application changes state, I loop through disabling and enabling visibility of multiple menus.

This issue I have is that when looping occasionally during the loop there are more menus visible than what will fit on the screen, causing a wrap, which then causes everything on the main form to resize, and resize back resulting in slowness and a huge flicker.

I have tried the Disable and Enable align on the main form, doesn't have any impact.

I have done the WM_SETREDRAW trick on the main form, however while it stops it drawing, calling invalidate afterwards, doesn't get some of the children controls to redraw correctly. An example of what won't redraw is the tabs on a TPageControl.

An other point that may be of relevance, is that code is called from a TTabSheet::OnShow callback.

Ideally I would like to find a BeginUpdateMainMenu and EndUpdateMainMenu method, however I can't find on in the VCL documentation or the Win32 documentation.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use action lists which have an overall disabled option

Comment: Thanks David. I'm under the pump to get this working quickly, and the menu system is quite complex, parsed from XML and has Lua controlling enabled/disabled based on various situations. No doubt your suggestion is probably the correct one, however I don't have time to learn about action lists at the moment. I was wondering if there is something hacky I can do with my current setup - maybe something obvious I am missing? Thanks

Comment: Rather bizarre that my comment was removed!

Comment: yea, why did you remove it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a technical answer but I'm thinking from an end user "useablilty" point of view : how easy would it be for him/her to use "more menus visible than what will fit on the screen"
Do you have the possibility to group the menu items in some way so that they could be dysplayed in sub-menus ?